# Playing every second different WAV sound ? From disk or from memmory?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

i need create wav player, that play every second different audio file.

1s second - play 1.wav
2nd second - play 2.wav
3,4,5,6,:59 - play xxx.wav

I dont know, if is good idea read from disk file and play it. second per second... or better way : load all files into memory, and play it from memory (much faster)

What do you think about it ?

Comment: Why not have 1 big .wav file rather than breaking it up into small sections?

Comment: Why not trying booth ways and having a look which works better? This is not a big deal at all ;)

Comment: Because i need dynamically compose it ...
I have many many combinations of "content" of sounds, and this is small by size, big by avaiablility of combining

Comment: You ask which way is "better" without saying what you consider to be "better". What is "better"?

Comment: better is faster (no lags)

Answer (score 0):

If the list of files is small - load them. Loading 3600 files for an hour of music is - not smart, otoh.

> I dont know, if is good idea read from disk file and play it. second per second... or 
>   better way : load all files into memory, and play it from memory (much
>   faster)

Consider the third option. Load the next seconds file into memory while you play the current one.

Comment: Complete lenght of audio is 10 minutes. in this 10 minutes is apporx 50 wav files (lenght of one file is 1-5 sec). co 90% of time is silent, but i need play "eight" in 8 minute of countdown

Comment: So, files are sparse and not reused. Load them on demand, preferable a little in advance. No sense in wasting memory on something you do not regularly use.